# How can I construct an AngularJS state parameter in the view by concatenation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Using the AngularJD `ui-router`, I have defined a state `myState` that takes 3 parameters: `stateParam1`, `stateParam2` and `stateParam3`.

In my view the variables `var1` and `var2` are already defined. I pass them in as `stateParam1` and `stateParam2` respectively. That works. But for `stateParam3`, I want to send in the concatenation of the first two fields. But how do I do it? How can I concatenate `var1` and `var2` into a third variable that I send in as `stateParam3`?

```
<a ui-sref="myState({'stateParam1': var1, 'stateParam2': var2, 'stateParam3': WHAT_GOES_HERE? })">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simple string concatenation of those variables like `var1 + var2`

```
ui-sref="myState({'stateParam1': var1, 'stateParam2': var2, 'stateParam3': var1 + var2 })">
```